# Get distinct values according to time in pandas using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have a df with value

```
a   b      time

1   test   2020-01-06 16:49:36.742 
2   test   2019-01-07 16:49:36.742
3   test   2015-01-07 16:49:36.742
4   car    2016-01-07 16:49:36.742
5   train  2017-01-07 16:49:36.742
6   train  2012-01-07 16:49:36.742
7   bat    2011-01-07 16:49:36.742
```

Get distinct values a/c to the earliest date [format of date : datetime[ns] ]

like this

```
a   b      time


1   test    2015-01-07 16:49:36.742
2   car    2016-01-07 16:49:36.742
3   train   2012-01-07 16:49:36.742
4   bat    2011-01-07 16:49:36.742
```

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
( df.sort_values('time')
    .drop_duplicates('b',keep = 'first')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .assign(a = lambda x: x.index + 1) )
```

or with [`Groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)

```
 ( df.sort_values('time')
     .groupby('b',as_index=False).first()
     .reset_index(drop=True)
     .assign(a = lambda x: x.index + 1) )
```

---

if your data is sorted in **descending** order by the **time** column you can use:

```
( df.drop_duplicates('b',keep ='last')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .assign(a = lambda x: x.index + 1) )
```

or

```
(df.groupby('b',as_index=False).last()
   .reset_index(drop=True)
   .assign(a = lambda x: x.index + 1))
```

---

**Output**

```
   a      b                     time
0  1   test  2015-01-07-16:49:36.742
1  2    car  2016-01-07-16:49:36.742
2  3  train  2012-01-07-16:49:36.742
3  4    bat  2011-01-07-16:49:36.742
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Groupby and min()

Just make sure 'time' is a timestamp

```
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df_distinct=df.groupby('b')['time'].min().reset_index()
```